# Content of one tab not displayed correctly

Tags: jquery, html

In my code output when in click intro, about or disclaimer it works okay. It gives the desired output. However when I click "Enrolled Students" it does not give the data which is inside div.

```html
<ul id="info-nav">
  <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></li>
  <li><a href="#enrolledStudents">View Enrolled Students</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="info">
  <div id="intro">
    Welcome to <strong>Student Module Application</strong>....
  </div>
  <div id="about">
    Student Module Application was founded in early days when …
  </div>
  <div id="disclaimer">
    Disclaimer! This service is not intended for the those …
  </div>
  <div id="enrolledStudents">
    <div id="bio">
      <h2>Enrolled Students...</h2>

      <button id="btn1"><h3>Hamza</h3></button>
      <p id="panel1">Content about Hamza</p>

      <button id="btn2"><h3>Mohsin</h3></button>
      <p id="panel2">Content about Mohsin</p>

      <button id="btn3"><h3>Hammad</h3></button>
      <p id="panel3">Content about Hammad</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my script tag is this........ every thing works fine except when i click 
      enrolled students it does not given the students details which is ion bio.

```
  <script>
        $('#info div').hide();

        $('#info-nav li').click(function(e) 
           {
              $('#info div').hide();
              $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
              $(this).addClass('current');
              var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
              $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
              e.preventDefault();
           }).eq(0).addClass('current');
   </script>
```

Comment: Where is the JS code?

Comment: Please use the `edit` button under the question to add code. As you can now see, code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your js code to this: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/OEZxQm

Here, You just need to hide immediate div so **>** selects immediate children and hide that only so it works perfect!!!

```
$('#info > div').hide();
$('#info-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $('#info > div').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');
    var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
}).eq(0).addClass('current');
```

A space selector **('#info  div')** will select all deep descendants whereas a greater than > selector **('#info > div')** will only select all immediate descendants.

Comment: can you explain in detail @bhumi shah

Answer (score 0):

The code `$('#info div').hide()` hides all the `div` inside the `div` with id `info` so when you click on `View Enrolled Students` there are multiple child `div`s which are hidden that is why you don't see those visible just by `$('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');`

What you can do is add a new class say `linkedDiv` to all the parent `div` that is the content of the `a` link. And hide/show those `div`s only.

```js
$('.linkedDiv').hide(); 
$('#info-nav li').click(function(e) {
  $('.linkedDiv').hide();
  $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass('current');
  var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
  $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast'); 
  e.preventDefault(); 
}).eq(0).addClass('current');
```

```css
.current a{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="info-nav">
            <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#disclaimer">Disclaimer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#enrolledStudents">View Enrolled Students</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="info">
            <div id="intro" class='linkedDiv'>
               Welcome to <strong>Student Module Application</strong>....
            </div>
            <div id="about" class='linkedDiv'>
               Student Module Application was founded in early days when …
            </div>
            <div id="disclaimer" class='linkedDiv'>
               Disclaimer! This service is not intended for the those …
            </div>
            <div id="enrolledStudents" class='linkedDiv'>
              <div id="bio">
                <h2>Enrolled Students...</h2>

                <button id="btn1"><h3>Hamza</h3></button>
                <p id="panel1">Content about Hamza</p>

                <button id="btn2"><h3>Mohsin</h3></button>
                <p id="panel2">Content about Mohsin</p>

                <button id="btn3"><h3>Hammad</h3></button>
                <p id="panel3">Content about Hammad</p>
              </div> 
            </div>
```